# Comparing two different column in a book and get number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, conditional-statements

I am quite new to SQL and I am trying to find the number of records for the same ship_name. Below is an example of my current data.

```
time_column_1   ship_name  ship_arrival_time  *number_of_records*
27/3/2017 4:00   TOMY        28/3/2017 8:00      *0*  
27/3/2017 8:00   TOMY        28/3/2017 8:00      *3* 
27/3/2017 12:00  TOMY        28/3/2017 8:00      *4* 
27/3/2017 16:00  TOMY        28/3/2017 8:00      *7* 
27/3/2017 16:00   HX         28/3/2017 8:00      *0*

arrival_time_of_containers   ship_name
27/3/2017 6:00                TOMY
27/3/2017 7:00                TOMY
27/3/2017 8:00                TOMY
27/3/2017 10:00               TOMY
27/3/2017 13:00               TOMY
27/3/2017 13:00               TOMY
```

Above are examples of the data I have. I am trying to compare the arrival_time_of_container against time_column_1 and trying to get the number_of_records_column.

The number_of_records_column should not increase until the arrival_time_of_container column matches time_column_1, getting all the records before that in total.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: so how would your desired result look like?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment. The desired result should look like the example of the current data that I have included, just that I have trouble finding out the values of the number_of_records column.

Comment: I am confused. so when you say 'current data' you meant the desired result? And when you say 'exmaples of the data' you mean data you are working with?

Comment: This is the data that I am working with, currently I am trying to find the number_of_records_column.

Comment: @Faheera I think people are confused as they would expect to see data you have first and then data result you want to achieve as second - clearly stated which is which. We are are sequential human beings here after all :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback, I have highlighted the column that I want to find with asterisks.

Comment: how can we compare the arrival_time_of_container against time_column_1 when time_column_1 is in your result table? I think some information are still missing

Comment: Hi, I desire time_column_1 to be in my result table, and currently time_column_1 is in my current data as well. All the columns you see here are in my current data and I would also like them to be part of the desired result with the number_of_records column, which I am trying to find.